# What type of plug-in is Fruity Loop's Gross Beat?

Tags: audio, effects, plugins

What is the name for the type of effect that Fruity Loop's Gross Beat plug-in creates? How does that type of effect work?

Comment: As of when this question was asked, an alternative to Gross Beat that works in other DAWs is Effectix ($129): http://www.sugar-bytes.de/content/products/Effectrix/

Answer (score 3):

I would say Gross Beat falls under the time manipulation category, it just creates stutters by jumbling the audio around a bit, and changes the speed or volume level on certain tracks. I imagine that most of the sound effects created by gross beat could be achieved quite simply by cutting up and automating property's of audio clips. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I've heard it refered to as a "glitch effect", it does now work in other DAWs -

Similar effects that come to mind would be:
Sugar-Bytes - Effectix,
Native Instruments - The Finger,
Illformed - Glitch,
iZotope - Stutter Edit,